# Experimental method decorator that enforces method paramater type with TypeScript 5

Tags: typescript

I've got a method decorator that only works on methods where the first parameter is a certain type. Looks like this:

```
interface Foo { foo: string }
interface PayloadMap { 'foo': Foo }

type TypedMethodDecorator<T> = {
  (target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(payload: T) => void>): void;
};

declare function MyDecorator<Topic extends keyof PayloadMap, Payload = PayloadMap[Topic]>(topic: Topic): TypedMethodDecorator<Payload>;

class TestClass {
  @MyDecorator('foo')
  works(payload: Foo) {}

  // @ts-expect-error: wrong payload type
  @MyDecorator('foo')
  nope(payload: string) {}
}
```

This works up through TS 4.9. With 5.3, it no longer works. There's no error with the second use. Can I tweak this so it continues to work with the newer version?

[TS 4.9 playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7JpgLmQGcwpQBzZAXwFgAoUSWRFABTgE8AbdOAEwCycAA45kAcnzoJRDFjr0GYTiJQAVVRCEQwAC3T8AIhAToocMOYA86gHzIAvDgbJkACjBwoFXUXQARgBWpmAANMgiUOhqUCoA0hCcRKTkIFQAPiScALYB6NwR-BDECOQiVlBEmmr8bNGxKial5ZXW7iJcvALVAJRODgBu6MD8dr1Ew6MA3AzUs0r0xQjc3igwAK4gCGDA6CDIgpwmZhZt6jHACMgQAB6QIPzEyADWSegwyBw8fEKiEd9uvwnF8ur9hCIANoXERXAC6dk8lwQ1WRE2QNW0gl0BmMpnMlhsgN%20dgWDBWcGIz3UJTAAGFVlSXPQ3AABI4nAmVdxSTASXquZAAd3ML2IHTBPTQmH62EUgoA9ArkKywMQALR3NQ7TVQaJVYXRdKRSXAlRqQXs474s7mHnSfmCkAxCASn5S1KUWWKRRAA)
[TS 5.3 playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true&ts=5.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7JpgLmQGcwpQBzZAXwFgAoUSWRFABTgE8AbdOAEwCycAA45kAcnzoJRDFjr0GYTiJQAVVRCEQwAC3T8AIhAToocMOYA86gHzIAvDgbJkACjBwoFXUXQARgBWpmAANMgiUOhqUCoA0hCcRKTkIFQAPiScALYB6NwR-BDECOQiVlBEmmr8bNGxKial5ZXW7iJcvALVAJRODgBu6MD8dr1Ew6MA3AzUs0r0xQjc3igwAK4gCGDA6CDIgpwmZhZt6jHACMgQAB6QIPzEyADWSegwyBw8fEKiEd9uvwnF8ur9hCIANoXERXAC6dk8lwQ1WRE2QNW0gl0BmMpnMlhsgN%20dgWDBWcGIz3UJTAAGFVlSXPQ3AABI4nAmVdxSTASXquZAAd3ML2IHTBPTQmH62EUgoA9ArkKywMQALR3NQ7TVQaJVYXRdKRSXAlRqQXs474s7mHnSfmCkAxCASn5S1KUWWKRRAA)

Note I'm still using experimentalDecorators with TS 5, not the new standard decorators.

The error I get (and want) with 4.9 is this:

```
Argument of type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(payload: string) => void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(payload: Foo) => void>'.
  Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '((payload: string) => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((payload: Foo) => void) | undefined'.
      Type '(payload: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(payload: Foo) => void'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In case you need to leave the generic type for Payload, you can manually set those types inside the decorator like this:

```
interface Foo { foo: string }
interface PayloadMap { 'foo': Foo }

type TypedMethodDecorator<T> = (
  target: object,
  propertyKey: string | symbol,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(payload: T) => void>
) => void;

declare function MyDecorator<Topic extends keyof PayloadMap, Payload = PayloadMap[Topic]>(topic: Topic): TypedMethodDecorator<Payload>;

class TestClass {
  @MyDecorator('foo')
  works(payload: Foo) {}

  @MyDecorator<'foo', Foo>('foo')
  nope(payload: string) {}
}
```

It will highlight the same error in the v5.3 TypeScript playground:

```
Unable to resolve the signature of the method decorator when called as an expression.
  Argument of type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(payload: string) => void>' is not assignable to the parameter of type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(payload: Foo) => void>'.
    Types of the property 'value' are incompatible.
      Type '((payload: string) => void) | undefined' is not assignable to the type '((payload: Foo) => void) | undefined'.
        Type '(payload: string) => void' is not assignable to the type '(payload: Foo) => void'. (1241)
```

2. If you don't need a generic type, you can replace the MyDecorator type with PayloadMap[Topic] like this:

```
declare function MyDecorator<Topic extends keyof PayloadMap>(topic: Topic): TypedMethodDecorator<PayloadMap[Topic]>;
```

It will still produce the same error you expect.

**Note**: While the error persists in TypeScript version 5.3, the expected behavior observed in version 4.9 can be achieved by using either of the two cases presented here. Despite the TypeScript update, these modifications help maintain compatibility with the desired functionality.

Comment: Nice, thanks. The second way does what I need. I had made Payload a generic parameter so I could compute a new type in a convenient place (it's a bit more complicated in my real implementation), not because I wanted it to be set by the caller or inferred at the call site. Removing that parameter and calculating the type in a different place solved the issue.